# Can an electric steamer with a timer be used to cook raw food on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat

Can one use an electric steamer with a timer to cook a meal for Shabbat lunch?

If one puts raw food on the device and sets a timer before Shabbat for it to be activated on Saturday and start the cooking process so that it can be fully cooked for lunchtime is it permissible?

If not, is there any way one can have a hot plate for lunch?

Comment: Welcome, Antonio! We don't allow questions that ask for a Personal Halachic Decision, so I have reworded your question so that it doesn't get closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31994/759

Comment: Do you mean that the cooking itself is done on Shabbat?

Comment: The biblical and rabbinic laws of bishul are quite nuanced and complicated and practical questions should really be asked of a competent rabbi.  That said, there are many ways that the Sabbath observant have warm food on Shabbat such as using slow cookers or reheating precooked food on atypical cooking surfaces.

Comment: See e.g. https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shehiya and https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Permissible_ways_to_heat_up_food_on_Shabbat

Comment: Is the question based on the idea that steam is different than fire or electricity as far as cooking on Shabbos?

Comment: relevant sources: https://www.aish.com/jl/jewish-law/shabbat/22-Bishul---Part-4-The-Heat-of-the-Matter.html (under Slow cooker) and https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/447

Answer (score -1):

Most poskim seem to forbid it because it lessens our respect for shabbat; while there are some who permit it. I've heard that R' Yitzchak Abadi permits such an arrangement, although I haven't seen an official psak stating so. He can be contacted through http://www.kashrut.org.

A good way to have hot food is to have it cooked before shabbat and also place it before shabbat in a crock pot or hot plate with a shabbat timer set for when you want to have the food ready (as is the practice of almost every shabbat-observant family).

See here for more information: http://www.zomet.org.il/eng/?CategoryID=160&ArticleID=4258